# Do equations of unconditional probability hold true after conditioning on both sides?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Reading a book in which the author conditions on both sides of the equation of non-conditional probability and states that they still hold after conditioning without further proving. I am wondering if this is always true.

---

Assume we have identity:

$$\mathbb{P}(f(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n))=F(\mathbb{P}(f_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)),\mathbb{P}(f_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)),\ldots,\mathbb{P}(f_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)))$$

where $A_i, i=1,2,\ldots,n$ are some events; $f,f_1,\ldots,f_m$ are functions on sets using set operations including $\cup$, $\cap$, $\setminus$;$F$ is a function defined on $[0,1]^m$. Then if I condition both sides on event X, do I have:

$$\mathbb{P}(f(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid X)=F(\mathbb{P}(f_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid X),\mathbb{P}(f_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid X),\ldots,\mathbb{P}(f_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid X))$$

---

Step 2: sometimes the original equation is already conditional as below:

$$\mathbb{P}(f(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n))=F(\mathbb{P}(f_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)),\mathbb{P}(f_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)),\ldots,\mathbb{P}(f_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)))\tag{*}$$

then do I have the (further) conditional version:

$$\mathbb{P}(f(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\cap X)=F(\mathbb{P}(f_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_1(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\cap X),\mathbb{P}(f_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_2(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\cap X),\ldots,\mathbb{P}(f_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\mid g_m(A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n)\cap X))$$

If any term of the original equation (*) is not conditional, simply use $f(...|X)$.

---

Step 3: Reverse the above statement, if "*conditional version*" holds true, how about the "*unconditional version*"?

---

*If* the above statements hold true, I can basically insert/remove conditional probability at will whenever I have an equation at hands, e.g.,

1. Since $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus B)=\mathbb{P}(A)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus B\mid X)=\mathbb{P}(A\mid X)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\mid X)$;
2. Since $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B_1)\mathbb{P}(A\mid B_1)+\mathbb{P}(B_2)\mathbb{P}(A\mid B_2)$ where $B_1$ and $B_2$ is a partition of sample space, then $\mathbb{P}(A\mid X)=\mathbb{P}(B_1\mid X)\mathbb{P}(A\mid B_1 \cap X)+\mathbb{P}(B_2\mid X)\mathbb{P}(A\mid B_2 \cap X)$
3. Since $\mathbb{P}(A\mid B\cap C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\mid C)}{\mathbb{P}(B\mid C)}$, we have $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

There are many posts (like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258379/why-is-pa-bc-pbc-pab-c) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377816/applying-law-of-total-probability-to-conditional-probability)) proving that the above statement is correct for a specific equation, but I haven't found a post handling the issue in a general way.

Comment: A conditional distribution is still a probability distribution. So any property of unconditional probabilities $\mathbb{P}(\cdot)$ holds for conditional probabilities $\mathbb{P}(\cdot \mid X)$.

Comment: @angryavian So this is enough as a rigorous *proof*? Does it use anything like [three axioms of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), don't find it *enough* myself lol. Also, how about the other way around (as I mentioned in step 3)?

Comment: @angryavian I added a bounty to the question. Please consider writing an answer, if you like.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking, but if the authors prove the following: whatever the probability measure $\mu$ might be, the identity [X] holds. Then you can apply the identity [X] when $\mu = \mathbf{P}$ and when $\mu(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(\cdot \mid E)$ where $E$ is any event. If, however, the authors prove that for some _specific_ probability measure $\mu_0,$ identity [X] holds, then you will need to reprove [X] for any other probability measure. (This comment is the essentially the same as @angryavian. )

Comment: @WilliamM. How can we prove the claim? By claim I mean: "If the identity [X] holds for $\mu = \mathbf{P}$ then it holds for $\mu(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(\cdot \mid E)$ where $E$ is an event."

Comment: Also it's well known that independence of two events does not imply that they are conditionally independent given a third event. It seems to me that the claim doesn't hold in this case.

Comment: I think it will depend on what [X] is because as @S.H.W pointed out, some identities hold for $\mathbf{P}$ but they don't hold for (some of) the condition probability measure.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks. I would appreciate if you could post an answer so I can award the bounty. Specifically, I'm looking for identities that hold for $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mu(\cdot) = \mathbf{P}(\cdot \mid E)$.

Comment: Do you assume that equality hold for some given events $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ or for every events?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan The equality holds for every events. Another example is from information theory. We have the chain rule $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X)$. Then conditioned on $Z$, we have $H(X,Y|Z) = H(X|Z) + H(Y|X,Z)$. There are many usage of this conditioning on both sides of an identity. Surprisingly, conditioning doesn't work for the independent RVs.